# Blackberry BrowserField / BrowserContent

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I'm working with the **BrowserFieldDemo** (JDE 7.1.0) and on the event `Event.EVENT_BROWSER_CONTENT_CHANGED`, a `BrowserContent` object is retrieved with

```
(BrowserContent) browserContentChangedEvent.getSource();
```

My question is: can I get a [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) instance from the event information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the **old** `BrowserFieldDemo`.  This code has been around for a long time (since way before 7.1), and uses code that's quite a bit more complex than what's been required since BB OS 5.0.

If you want to work directly with [net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html), then you should check out the `BrowserField2Demo`.

In Eclipse, goto **BlackBerry** -> **Import** -> **BlackBerry Samples** -> **BrowserField2Demo**.

If you then use the newer `BrowserField`, you can attach a [BrowserFieldListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldListener.html), which will get called back during normal browser events, similar to the method you mentioned from the old `BrowserFieldDemo`.  In all those callbacks, you'll see that you do get passed a true instance of `BrowserField`, as you wanted.

```java
 void documentAborted(BrowserField browserField, Document document) ;         
 void documentCreated(BrowserField browserField, ScriptEngine scriptEngine, Document document);             
 void documentError(BrowserField browserField, Document document);              
 void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document);              
 void documentUnloading(BrowserField browserField, Document document);              
 void downloadProgress(BrowserField browserField, ContentReadEvent event);
```

Comment: Thanks Nate! I think you gave the right answer ~ although I was hoping I could just doing something in the old/simple BrowserFieldDemo.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think once you get used to it, you'll find that the new BrowserField (also known as browserfield2) is actually simpler to use.

Comment: I appreciate your input.

Ok . . . I just did a build of the "BrowserField2Demo" supplied with JDE 7.1.0 and when I try to OTA load it onto my Torch 9850 it reports "Error 907 Invalid COD". Ouch!

Comment: That's a separate problem.  There are a few different reasons this could happen.  I would recommend going to google and searching with the string: `blackberry Error 907 Invalid COD site:stackoverflow.com`, or maybe `site:blackberry.com`.  Try the suggestions you find.  If that doesn't work, post a new question.  Thanks. (P.S. I would also certainly try installing your app via USB, rather than over the air, if that's a possibility.)